# Automatically checking out solution - because new files are in a non-source-controlled folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, version-control, umbraco, solution

I've recently upgraded to VS 2013, and I'm seeing that my site's solution is automatically being checked out on opening.

I suspect that this is because the site uses Umbraco, and consequently the `App_Data` folder is often cleared down... Umbraco will then re-populate indexes and config files within that folder when the site is run.

I've believe I've excluded the `App_Data` source from source control (right-clicking shows an option to <kbd>Add files to source control</kbd>), and that therefore new items within that folder shouldn't affect the solution, but is that right?
I know if I create a new file in, say, the images folder in the solution that it will be automatically added to the project (which is quite handy)... is there any chance it's doing the same thing with `App_Data`?  Is there a setting somewhere to alter that behaviour?

Comment: The only things in `App_Data` that you ever want in source control are the `packages` folder and `access.config`. Everything else I've ever seen in App_Data is cache or log related. I would exclude the rest of App_Data from the project. I do this by right clicking on those folders/files and clicking "Exclude from Project". Are you saying that when you run the site, new cache files are automatically "Included in the Project"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply bowserm, much appreciated...

Looking at the contents of the App_Data folder, I don't think any of them look like they're part of the project... there is no 'include' or 'exclude/remove' option for anything below the App_Data folder itself.  Maybe it's something else, which isn't showing within the 'Pending Changes Filter' which is triggering the solution to get checked-out.

Comment: Oh, and although I have an 'access.config' file, it just contains an empty access tag... and I don't have a 'packages' folder.

Comment: Do you know if you using a "Website" project? Or a "Web Application" project? Also, no worries about not having a packages folder. It is just an xml record of what packages you have installed through the umbraco backoffice. My guess is that you haven't installed any, yet. The access.config is used to store your "public access" settings. If you wanted to restrict access to some of your pages to members, this is where that data would be stored.

Comment: Ah, not sure, I didn't create the project.  Right-clicking on 'localhost' in the project gives options to 'Build Web Site' and 'Publish Web App'.

Comment: This may be moot though - yesterday my team leader and I cleaned up IIS, removing a whole bunch of redundant websites, and duplicates under IIS Express.  I've done an 'Undo' on the solution checkout (and all the App_Data folders and files) and then re-run the site and re-opened the solution... it's not checking out the solution!

Comment: The App_Data files get marked with a red tick, but shortly after they disappear, as if it's catching up to the fact I've not included them in the project?